# Tell whether people arrived close or not

Tags: python, function, statistics, computer-science, intervals

Write a function that takes two arguments to determine length of interval used to determine if arrivals are close or not. Should return true is close and false if not

Idk I can’t figure it out.

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem or test question. Surely you aren't asking someone else to just give you the answer. Take a look at [this guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) for how to ask these kinds of questions.

Answer (score -1):

I don’t have enough reputation to comment, so this has to be an answer, I’m sorry, you’re going to have to explain your issue in more detail in order to get help.

Comment: Comments aren't meant to be posted as answers.

Comment: I don’t have enough rep to comment.

Comment: that’s why I posted here

Answer (score -1):

Provide more specific details:

- Are the arguments integers?
- What does "close" mean?
- What do you mean by "length of interval"?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).